# Different length arrays to one CSV

Tags: arrays, powershell, export-to-csv

If you have multiple arrays of different length, how can you export these to a single csv in powershell?

```
Array1 = 1,2,3 
Array2 = Bob,smithy,Alex,Jeremy 
Array3 = yes,no
```

Output CSV

```
Number  Name  Valid 
———————————————————  
1      Bob    Yes  
2      Smithy no  
3      Alex
       Jeremy
```

Basically each array would be in its own header column.

Tried lines like

```
Array1 | Select-Object Number | export-csv -Path C:\Path
```

This works for singular arrays to singular csv files

But if I try

```
Array1, Array2, Array3 | Select-Object Number, Name, Valid | export-csv -Path C:\Path
```

I just get the header names and no values in the columns

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it is with a [`for` loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2).

```bash
$Array1 = 1, 2, 3
$Array2 = 'Joe Bloggs', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe'
$Array3 = 'Yes', 'No'

$export = for($i = 0; $i -lt [Linq.Enumerable]::Max([int[]] ($Array1.Count, $Array2.Count, $Array3.Count)); $i++) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Number = $Array1[$i]
        Name   = $Array2[$i]
        Valid  = $Array3[$i]
    }
}
$export | Export-Csv path\to\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

Another example using a [function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2), the logic is more or less the same except that there is more overhead involved, since this function can handle an indefinite amount of arrays coming from the pipeline.

```
function Join-Array {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        [object[]] $InputObject,

        [parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [string[]] $Columns
    )

    begin {
        $inputDict = [ordered]@{}
        $index = 0
    }
    process {
        try {
            if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
                return $inputDict.Add($Columns[$index++], $InputObject)

            }

            foreach ($item in $InputObject) {
                $inputDict.Add($Columns[$index++], $item)
            }
        }
        catch {
            if ($_.Exception.InnerException -is [ArgumentNullException]) {
                $errorRecord = [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
                    [Exception] 'Different count between input arrays and Columns.',
                    'InputArrayLengthMismatch',
                    [Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidOperation,
                    $InputObject
                )
                $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($errorRecord)
            }
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }
    end {
        foreach ($pair in $inputDict.GetEnumerator()) {
            $count = $pair.Value.Count
            if ($count -gt $max) {
                $max = $count
            }
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++) {
            $out = [ordered]@{}
            foreach ($column in $inputDict.PSBase.Keys) {
                $out[$column] = $inputDict[$column][$i]
            }
            [pscustomobject] $out
        }
    }
}
```

The usage would be pretty easy, the arrays to join / zip can be passed through the [pipeline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2) and the desired column names defined positionally:

```
$Array1 = 1, 2, 3
$Array2 = 'Joe Bloggs', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe'
$Array3 = 'Yes', 'No'
$Array4 = 'hello', 'world', 123, 456

$Array1, $Array2, $Array3, $Array4 | Join-Array Number, Name, Valid, Test |
    Export-Csv path\to\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I did not know you could assign a `for` loop to a variable in that way, though in hindsight it makes some sense if each iteration just leaves a value on the pipeline. I'll definitely be using this technique more in the future.

Answer (score 2):

For quite some time I've been maintaining a [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In PowerShell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)).
Its main purpose is joining tables (aka lists of objects) based on a related column (aka property) defined by the `-on` parameter using a user (aka scripter) friendly syntax which as many joining options as possible. This has led to a few implicit features that could be used in your specific request:

- If there is no relation defined (the `-on` parameter is omitted), it is assumed that you want to do a side-by-side join of the tables (aka lists)

  - If the tables (or lists) are not equal in size, a common (inner) join will end when either lists ends. A full join (e.g. `FullJoin-Object` alias `FullJoin` or a left - or right join) at the other hand, will join the complete respective lists
- An array of scalars (e.g. strings rather than custom objects) is joined as being a list of objects where the (default) column (aka property) name is `Value`

  - If both sides contain a list of scalars, the output will be a  `[Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]` list for each left and right item, containing those items.
- Join commands can be chained: `... | Join ... | Join ...`
- If the columns (aka properties) provided in the tables (aka lists) overlap, they will be merged in an array ( `<property name> = <left property value>, <right property value>`) by default, which items could also be assigned to a specific name (prefix) using the `-Name` parameter. This parameter can be used with every join command in the chain.

All together this means that you could implement your task with the following command line:

```
$Array1 | FullJoin $Array2 | FullJoin $Array3 -Name Number, Name, Valid
```

```
Number Name       Valid
------ ----       -----
     1 Joe Bloggs Yes
     2 John Doe   No
     3 Jane Doe
```

**Update** (2023-22-06)

Since version `3.8.1` it is possible to dynamically add arrays (starting from an empty array initiator), see also [issue #42](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object/issues/42). Taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76526689/1701026) question as an example:

As a new transposed jagged array:

```
$dummy = @(("a","b","c"),("1","2","3"),("John","Jane","Smith"))
$dummy |Foreach-Object { $a = @() } { $a = $a | FullJoin $_ }

$a.ForEach{ $_ -Join '|' }

a|1|John
b|2|Jane
c|3|Smith
```

converted to an object collection:

```
$a | FullJoin @() -Name foo, bar, baz

foo bar baz
--- --- ---
a   1   John
b   2   Jane
c   3   Smith
```

dynamically naming:

```
$dummy |Foreach-Object { $a = @(); $n = 1 } { $a = $a | FullJoin $_ -Name "Name$(($n++))" }
$a

Name1 Name2 Name3
----- ----- -----
a     1     John
b     2     Jane
c     3     Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure the data to pivot it into one array (presented here in pseudo-json):

```
[ 
  {"1", "Bob", "Yes"}, 
  {"2", "Smithy", "no"}, 
  {"3", "Alex", ""}, 
  {"", "Jeremy", ""} 
]
```

Note how the missing fields still appear with empty placeholders.

Once you've pivoted your data this way, writing it to a CSV file is trivial, as are many other tasks (this is the better way to structure things in the first place).

Comment: If each array is being created from importing data in other csv how would you make one big array with multiple imports?