# Paired enumeration of two arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, enumeration

I have 2 arrays: I need to sort them in foreach to modify 1 file.

1 array with dbs name like:

```
$dbs = ['Honda', 'Toyota', 'BMW', 'Opel']
```

2nd array with their size like:

```
$dbsSize = ['123', '300', '222', '143']
```

and I can sort names in foreach like

```
foreach ($db in $dbs){
  # some logic..
}
```

How can I sort 2nd array in the same `foreach` so I can use it in the same loop

Like this:

```
foreach ($db in $dbs) {
  # some logic with $db
  # and here I need some logic with $dbsSize 
}
```

but to sort out $dbsSize like $dbs because I need the result like :

```
Honda
123

Toyota
300
```

etc.

Do I need to create another loop?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any sorting in your code, I only see enumeration. Seems like you want to enumerate both collections sequentially, in that case you would need to use a [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.3) loop instead of [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
$dbs = "['Honda', 'Toyota', 'BMW', 'Opel']" | ConvertFrom-Json
$dbsSize = "['123', '300', '222', '143']" | ConvertFrom-Json

for($i = 0; $i -lt [math]::Max($dbs.Count, $dbsSize.Count); $i++) {
    $dbs[$i]
    $dbsSize[$i]
}
```

If you want to use a `foreach` loop and both collections have the same `Length`, then you can get the items of one of them (your choice which) via [indexing `[ ]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#index-operator--):

```
$i = 0
foreach($item in $dbs) {
    $item
    $dbsSize[$i++]
}
```

If you're looking to merge both arrays into objects, an easy way to do it is with the `function` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640422/15339544), the usage in this case would be:

```
$dbs, $dbsSize | Join-Array -Columns Car, Size
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you have two arrays where the indices determine which element of the one array belongs to the element in the other array.

It is unclear how you created them and why you did not create an array of **objects** with both properties together in the first place, but you can still do that like this:

```
$dbs     = 'Honda', 'Toyota', 'BMW', 'Opel'
$dbsSize = '123', '300', '222', '143'

$result = for($i = 0; $i -lt [math]::Max($dbs.Count, $dbsSize.Count); $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Car  = $dbs[$i]
        Size = $dbsSize[$i]
    }
}

# sort the items on 'Car' for instance
$result = $result | Sort-Object Car

# show on screen
$result

# save to structured CSV file you can open in Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\cars.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen using the above exampe looks like

```
Car    Size
---    ----
BMW    222 
Honda  123 
Opel   143 
Toyota 300
```