# Exporting multidimensional array to csv with format

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to export multidimensional array to csv with some formatting. Currently I'm just doing multidimensional array into object to export out but hoping to get some advice on formatting things.

```
$dummy = @(("a","b","c"),("1","2","3"),("John","Jane","Smith")

$obj = $dummy | Foreach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{ 'value' = $_ } }

$obj | Export-CSV -Path "C:\folder\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

with this code though my results are

[image]

hoping to make it look like

[image]

or any other way just be more formatted and not set as one cell so to speak

any advice or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: with the function on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640422/15339544) `$dummy | Join-Array -Columns foo, bar, baz | Export-Csv...` would do what you were expecting I believe

Comment: Nitpick - ```$dummy = @(("a","b","c"),("1","2","3"),("John","Jane","Smith")``` is not a [multi-dimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) , it's a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) (or array of arrays). A true multidimensional array would be declared like ```$arr = New-Object "string[,]" 5,5``` and accessed like ```$arr[1, 3] = "aaa"``` and ```$x = $arr[1, 3]```.