# How to import this Json data as a flat object rather than a nested object

Tags: json, powershell

I have a json file, its content is:

```
{
    "PID": [
        18988,
        23928,
        16656
    ],
    "Process": [
        "pwsh.exe",
        "pwsh.exe",
        "WindowsTerminal.exe"
    ],
    "WinID": [
        "0x1117b6",
        "0x130042",
        "0x600848"
    ]
}
```

I want to import it as a `PsCustom` object, I have tried `Get-Content -Path c:\temp\MyJson.json|ConvertFrom-Json` but this imports the data as a nested object:

```
PID                   Process                                   WinID
---                   -------                                   -----
{18988, 23928, 16656} {pwsh.exe, pwsh.exe, WindowsTerminal.exe} {0x1117b6, 0x130042, 0x600848}
```

I am expecting the following:

```
PID                   Process                                   WinID
---                   -------                                   -----
18988                       pwsh.exe                                                0x1117b6
23928                       pwsh.exe                                                0x130042
16656                       WindowsTerminal.exe                             0x600848
```

I have restructured the Json file multiple times, I am not sure where I am going wrong. I am open to changing the json file itself.

I would much rather solve this solution at the json file itself, rather in PowerShell with something like `...ConverFrom-Json| Where-Oject...`, can someone share with me the correct json format to provide for PowerShell, in this case?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: with the function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640422/15339544) you can do `$json.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { , $_.Value } | Join-Array $json.PSObject.Properties.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is imported as a single object with 3 properties: `PID`, `Process`, and `WinID`. Each of those properties contains 3 values. What you're requesting is to have 3 different objects, each with the `PID`, `Process`, and `WinID` properties and containing *one* of each of those values.

If you control the JSON you're capturing (I assume you do, since you're pulling it from a file), the simplest solution would be to change the way you're structuring the JSON to match what you expect:

```json
[
    {
        "PID": 18988,
        "Process": "pwsh.exe",
        "WinID": "0x1117b6"
    },
    {
        "PID": 23928,
        "Process": "pwsh.exe",
        "WinID": "0x130042"
    },
    {
        "PID": 16656,
        "Process": "WindowsTerminal.exe",
        "WinID": "0x600848"
    }
]
```

```
PS > $json | ConvertFrom-Json

  PID Process             WinID
  --- -------             -----
18988 pwsh.exe            0x1117b6
23928 pwsh.exe            0x130042
16656 WindowsTerminal.exe 0x600848
```

If you can't change the source JSON, this will turn what you have from one object into three:

```
PS > for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt 3; $i++){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PID = $json.PID[$i]
        Process = $json.Process[$i]
        WinID = $json.WinID[$i]
    }
}

  PID Process             WinID
  --- -------             -----
18988 pwsh.exe            0x1117b6
23928 pwsh.exe            0x130042
16656 WindowsTerminal.exe 0x600848
```

Comment: I restructed my json file to follow your example, perfect. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [JoinModule](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) from the PowerShell Gallery, you could dynamically (independently of the column names and sizes) join the properties list side-by-side:

```
$Object = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\MyJson.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$Transpose = @()
$Object.PSObject.Properties.Name | Foreach-Object {
    $Transpose = $Transpose | FullJoin-Object $Object.$_ -Name $_
}
$Transpose

  PID Process             WinID
  --- -------             -----
18988 pwsh.exe            0x1117b6
23928 pwsh.exe            0x130042
16656 WindowsTerminal.exe 0x600848
```

See also: